Godot 4.2.1: Calling get_data() on Image from NoiseTexture2D Returns Null
I am trying to retrieve image data from a NoiseTexture2D. I seem to be able to get an image resource, but as soon as I try to get the associated data via Image.get_data(), it only returns null
I am aware that image generation is run on a separate thread, so I tried using await texture.changed to see if that helps, but the result is the same.
A minimal example:
extends Node2D

# Sprite2D containing NoiseTexture2D (in my case 3844 x 2208)
@onready var _map_image: Sprite2D = $"Sprite2D":
    get:
        return _map_image

var _map_noise_image: Image

func _ready() -> void:
    await _map_image.texture.changed # does not solve the problem
    _map_noise_image = _map_image.texture.noise.get_image(
    _map_image.texture.get_width(), _map_image.texture.get_height(), false, true)
    
    var data = get_heightmap_data()

func get_heightmap_data():
    # returns null on non null image
    var heightmap_data = _map_noise_image.get_data()
    return heightmap_data

I’d be grateful for any pointers as to where I might be going wrong here
For reproducibility, the scene file for my test scene:
[gd_scene load_steps=4 format=3 uid="uid://4o4cf0atksay"]

[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://TestMap.gd" id="1_x1h5w"]

[sub_resource type="FastNoiseLite" id="FastNoiseLite_ybgxs"]
noise_type = 3
frequency = 0.0019

[sub_resource type="NoiseTexture2D" id="NoiseTexture2D_w5x8r"]
width = 3844
height = 2109
seamless = true
noise = SubResource("FastNoiseLite_ybgxs")

[node name="TestMap" type="Node2D"]
script = ExtResource("1_x1h5w")

[node name="Sprite2D" type="Sprite2D" parent="."]
texture = SubResource("NoiseTexture2D_w5x8r")


EDIT:
I "solved" it. It seems that it was only the debugger (both in VSCode and the editor) displaying the image data as null, while retrieving and printing the array and some values returned what I would would have expected.

await _map_image.texture makes no sense, don't do that. You are requesting an Image form the Noise object, not from the Texture2D. Is that what you want? I do not know why you would get a null anyway.

Thanks for the comment! I fixed the signal name for the await statement. I also tried getting the image as _map_noise_image = _map_image.texture.get_image(), but the heightmap_data is still null

I wonder what your node structure looks like. I tested your code on a simple Node2D>Sprite2D hierarchy, defining a NoiseTexture2D with noise for the sprite, and it works as expected. Are there other parts of your scene that may be affecting the output?

Pretty much like that. I set up a separate Node2D scene to run independently. I'll add the scene file in an edit.

I "solved" it. It seems that it was only the debugger (both in VSCode and the editor) displaying the image data as null, while retrieving and printing the array and some values returned what I would would have expected.
